# Connection timed-out exception when calling MongoDB Atlas with AWS EMR

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pyspark, amazon-emr, connector

I'm new to using AWS EMR and am trying to connect my AWS EMR cluster to my MongoDB Atlas database using the Mongo Spark Connector. I keep getting time out errors when trying to connect - here are some of the steps I've followed below:

I've used the connection string given in the MongoDB dashboard (mongodb+srv://:@news.qd3xn.mongodb.net/). However, when I try to create a Spark dataframe using my mongodb input, I keep getting a timed-out error. There have been several related threads pointing to issues with Spark and MongoDB version compatability. I'm currently using Python 3.7.6, Spark 2.4.5, MongoDB Spark Connector 2.4.2 and MongoDB Atlas 4.2.8.

I've tried to change the connection strings using every permutation of the Mongo Java driver code I could find. I'm able to connect to the MongoDB node using Mongo Compass and my local computer, just not with my EMR master node.
I was able to connect locally with the same code, but when I try to do a simple connection from EMR with pymongo, it doesn't work. Both my local machine and EMR are able to ping the mongodb node, but EMR doesn't connect. I have also whitelisted my computers IP address and the IP of the master node inside MongoDB.

I've started up my pyspark session in the EMR shell with the following code:

```
pyspark \
--conf "spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb+srv://<clustername>:<password>@news.qd3xn.mongodb.net/sample_airbnb?readPreference=primaryPreferred" \
--conf "spark.mongodb.input.database=sample_airbnb" \
--conf "spark.mongodb.input.collection=listingsAndReviews" \
--conf "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb+srv://<clustername>:<password>@news.qd3xn.mongodb.net/sample_airbnb" \
--conf "mongo.job.input.format=com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat" \
--packages "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.2"
```

After which I then attempt to create a Spark dataframe with:

```
df1 = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource") \
.option("uri","mongodb+srv://<clustername>:<password>@news.qd3xn.mongodb.net/sample_airbnb.listingsAndReviews").load()
```

The error message I get is:

```
 >>> df1 = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource") \
... .option("uri","mongodb+srv://<clustername>:<password>@news.qd3xn.mongodb.net/sample_airbnb.listingsAndReviews").load()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 172, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o109.load.
: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@1164cf33. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=news-shard-00-00.qd3xn.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=news-shard-00-01.qd3xn.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=news-shard-00-02.qd3xn.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:408)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.selectServer(BaseCluster.java:123)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AbstractMultiServerCluster.selectServer(AbstractMultiServerCluster.java:54)
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.getConnectedClusterDescription(MongoClientDelegate.java:154)
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.createClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:103)
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.getClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:284)
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:188)
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoDatabaseImpl.executeCommand(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:194)
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoDatabaseImpl.runCommand(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:163)
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoDatabaseImpl.runCommand(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:158)
        at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector$$anonfun$1.apply(MongoConnector.scala:237)
        at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector$$anonfun$1.apply(MongoConnector.scala:237)
        at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector$$anonfun$withDatabaseDo$1.apply(MongoConnector.scala:174)
        at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector$$anonfun$withDatabaseDo$1.apply(MongoConnector.scala:174)
        at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.withMongoClientDo(MongoConnector.scala:157)
        at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.withDatabaseDo(MongoConnector.scala:174)
        at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.hasSampleAggregateOperator(MongoConnector.scala:237)
        at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.MongoRDD.hasSampleAggregateOperator$lzycompute(MongoRDD.scala:221)
        at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.MongoRDD.hasSampleAggregateOperator(MongoRDD.scala:221)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MongoInferSchema$.apply(MongoInferSchema.scala:68)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.constructRelation(DefaultSource.scala:97)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I don't exactly understand what the error is saying. My cluster name is 'news' and it looks like there is some transformation happening where EMR is adjusting the name to access news-shard-00-00. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: I think you have TLS misconfigured.

Comment: Make sure you are using most recent release of mongodb driver too.